# There have some strange thing with Admob on my app

Tags: xcode, admob

Now I develop a app tool by xcode xib. I fount admob can't run well in app. If I put admob view upon other views. All other views can't get touch event. Like scrollview, tabbar...
But if I put admob view bottom of others. Admob can't touch again.

Code is here :

```
controller = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
controller.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
banner = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
                                                         rect.origin.x,
                                                         rect.origin.y,
                                                         GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                         GAD_SIZE_320x50.height
                                                        )];
banner.adUnitID = GAD_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
banner.rootViewController = controller;
GADRequest *request;
if (self._isDebuged) {
    request=[[GADRequest alloc]init];
    request.testing=TRUE;
}else {
    request=[GADRequest request];
}
[banner loadRequest:request];
[controller.view addSubview:banner];
```

My view struct:

```
window->rootViewController->rootView:

admob on the top
layer3:admob view container layer
layer2:tab bar
layer1:content view container
this cant touch any one except admob.

admob in the middle:
layer3:tab bar
layer2:admob view container layer
layer1:content view container
admob will cant display full screen because tabbar mask some area. and content cant touch.

admob at the bottom:
layer3:tab bar
layer2:content view container
layer1:admob view container layer
it works well with app, but cant touch admob any more.
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have some view placed underneath the AdMob view and they aren't getting touch events? Or that nothing that's a sibling of the AdMob view in the view hierarchy is getting events?

Comment: yes it is. and I modify my topic for show you my truble.

Comment: If you place an AdMob ad in a ScrollView or TabBar, the screen will not scroll if your touch began on the ad (the ad intercepts scrolling gestures), but any click events or scrolling gestures on sibling elements should still work.

Comment: Now I can only put admob to the middle and control content with parent gestures event. It is not good that event don't from it own.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ad banner's frame is too big to cover controller.view. Try something like this:

```
banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, 
                          GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height);
```

Comment: thx, but my banner frame is really just 350x50 size, posision is (0,0) , and I found many people have this question. http://www.google.com.hk/search?hl=zh-CN&newwindow=1&safe=strict&biw=1097&bih=666&q=admob+tabbar&oq=admob+tabbar&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=6932l8766l0l9044l8l8l1l0l0l0l263l849l0.2.2l4l0&gs_l=serp.3...6932l8766l0l9044l8l8l1l0l0l0l263l849l0j2j2l4l0